# How to remove automatic space inside a fo:block

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am writing a simple block with heading and fo:leader below is the sample code:

```
<fo:block font-weight="bold" font-size="4.3mm">
   Methods
   <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule" rule-thickness=".5mm" leader-length="267mm" color="cmyk(0,0,0,1)"/>
</fo:block>
```

So my expectation is text will come as heading and a rule just under that but I am seeing noticeable space between 'Methods' and rule

Attaching sample; I have highlighted the space with down arrows in the screenshot:

[image: displayImage]

What specification in `fo:block` or `fo:leader` can I use to remove that space?

Comment: Does `fo:leader alignment-baseline="before-edge"` help to close the gap?

Answer (score 2):

`fo:leader` is an inline FO. A shorter leader would typically immediately follow its preceding text; something like: "Methods_____". Because your `leader-length` is fixed to, presumably, the width of the body region, the leader is forced to the next line.

The space you are seeing is because the leader is on the alphabetic baseline of the next line, just like it is when it is on the same line as text. @MartinHonnen's solution moves the rule to the top of the space for its line, but there's still the space for a blank line below the shifted leader. An `fo:block` following the `fo:block` with the leader would look like it has a blank line before it (which might be what you want).

Other possible solutions include:

- Set `border-bottom` on the `fo:block` instead of using `fo:leader`
- Set `line-height` and/or `font-size` on the `fo:leader` so that it takes less space
- Use an empty `fo:block` with a border instead of the `fo:leader` and set `line-height`, `font-size`, `space-before`, and/or `space-after` to get the effect that you want.